Track progress in a thread with OpenMP
Im trying to create a programm that displays value from different thread every second, as an attempt at progress tracking functionality, but unfortunatly i cant seam to correctly parallelise this case at all.
Here is my attempt:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

volatile int counter = 0;
volatile int done = 0;

void print_every_second() {
    while (!done) {
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            printf("%d\n!", counter);
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
}

void increment_to_10_million() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10000000; ++i) {
        #pragma omp atomic
        counter++;
    }
    done = 1; 
}

int main() {
    #pragma omp parallel sections
    {
        #pragma omp section
        {
            print_every_second();
        }

        #pragma omp section
        {
            increment_to_10_million();
        }
    }

    printf("Both threads have finished.\n");

    return 0;
}


Functions end up not beign parallelised and only print_every_second ends up executing, at all. It is tested in VirtualBox with AMD Ryzen™ 7 2700 × 4 and gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0

The global variable i is completely unsynchronized. The "10 million" loop does nothing. It may as well just be replaced with i = 10000001; by the optimizer. If you want to report a value periodically, a better solution would be to use a local variable for your loop and then deliver that via a thread-safe mechanism. I don't know what OpenMP would do with a loop variable that's global. Either it would be unable to execute in parallel, or it would make thread-local copies of the loop variable.

I edited code to fix the issues of counting loop having no body, as well as printing function technicaly having no exit. attempted to sync with critical and atomic but the issue is still that only one of the threads launches.

You only call increment_to_10_million() once.

Yes? Just like it's supposed to? increment function increments count from 1 to 10 mil once, and print is supposed to print current value of count while it's still in the for loop.

Did you actually link to the OMP library? What happens if you call a function like omp_get_max_threads() -- does your program link without errors?

No errors. issue was that without specifying number of threads, program was running on one thread, and therefore not parallel.

AFAIK, Virtualbox used to have a 1 core vCPU by default. Multicore was not well supported for many years. IDK if this is still true nowadays though. I expect this not to be true anymore (unless someone use a old version or do not use hardware acceleration).

OpenMP is not really well suited for what you want to do. OpenMP is meant to parallelize program in a way a program should work without OpenMP annotation. If the behaviour is different in sequential, and it does not work, then something is wrong IMHO. For the same reason, in OpenMP, the number of threads should not impact the behaviour of a program either (but can in practice, due to FP associativity or things like this, though people tend to mitigate problems related to that as much as possible). To quote the specification ("1.3 Execution model"):

"The OpenMP API is intended to support programs that will execute correctly both as parallel programs (multiple threads of execution and a full OpenMP support library) and as sequential programs (directives ignored and a simple OpenMP stubs library). However, a conforming OpenMP program may execute correctly as a parallel program but not as a sequential program, or may produce diﬀerent results when executed as a parallel program compared to when it is executed as a sequential program."

Ok so i found an answer, and to some people who are more knowledgeable on omp this will be obvious.
The issue was solved by specifying number of threads using as by default it was using only 1 thread, basically making all pragma statements nonexistent.
Here is a corrected section:
int main() {
    #pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(2)
    {


The question is then, why is there only one thread by default? This has probably to do with the settings of your virtual machine, which is probably configured to use only one core of the host machine.
